Can I use the Query Loop as a component-dependency inside my block?
I am trying to make use of the core/query's capabilities in my block. Unfortunately, registering a block variation forfeits any control over what's output anywhere - the edit/save no longer work, because we're using core/query's, and there's no way to extend it.
Is there no way to register my own block type normally, and then inside, simply use QueryLoop's sidebar settings, queries, etc.?
For example, my edit.js file would look like this:
// `query` would contain the actual query response, `controls` would be what we'd output inside the sidebar
const { controls, query } = useQueryLoop();

<InspectorControls>
  {controls.map(control => control)}
  /* my controls would come here */
</InspectorControls>
<div {...blockProps}>
  {query.posts.map...
</div>

Naturally, my render.php would receive all the attributes provided by the front-end as well.
